# android project name and app name are different

Tags: android, android-studio, application-name

I am doing an android project using Android Studio. My project name is "Policia". I run the project on emulator and it shows another name "LoginActivity". Actually its the launcher activity. How can I solve this??

[image: In the picture, left side is snap shot from studio and right side is from emulator.]

Comment: post code of your xml.

Comment: So, I have to set the app_name as the title of main activity. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main activity listed in manifest file see the `android:label` value

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Then see `string.xml` file in resource (`res`) folder to see the actual String value of `app_name`. Change it to whatever you desire.

Main activity will be the one with following intent-filter

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: app_name = Policia in String file

Comment: In that case you should see `Policia` in the Action bar. What text does it show there?

Comment: sorry. i set the label of main activity to the activity_name, just like other activities.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you tried to change the label of your launcher activity (activity that is started when the user starts your app) from the `string/app_name` attribute in the manifest file to something else.

[image]

To change the label(title) of your activity without any strange behaviour, go to your activity and add the label there. In the `onCreate()` method, do this:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTitle(R.string.your_app_title); //<--change title to whatever you want

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


}
```